# Problems using pedometer application - http://code.google.com/p/pedometer/

Tags: android

I m using the followinf application ==> [pedometer](http://code.google.com/p/pedometer/)

As i run this pedometer application on my emulator it starts showing some random values ...so could you please suggest me some ways in order to run this application on android emulator!

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

The emulator has no real control over its accelerometers, use this to fix it. But I would really just test on a real device.
http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Comment: I have tried this but it is still showing the same problem :( :(